# How to copy then paste formulas from one workbook to another with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have an existing VBA code that copies an Excel worksheet from my source workbook (`Sourcewb`) into a new destination workbook (`Destwb`) but pastes values only. I need a specific range (`D31:E38`) in the `Destwb` to include the formulas from the source workbook.  I found this code:

```
Range("A1:I1105").Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B2")
```

On this site (another question) that seems related but don't know how to modify it to work in my application. I have added a comment line " 'Insert total formulas in Calc sheet" for where I think the additional code would go.  Here is my existing code:

```
Set Sourcewb = ActiveWorkbook

'Copy the sheet to a new workbook
Sheets("Calculation").Copy
Set Destwb = ActiveWorkbook

'Determine the Excel version and file extension/format
With Destwb
    If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
        'You use Excel 97-2003
        FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
    Else
        'You use Excel 2007-2013
            FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
        End If
End With

'Change all cells in the worksheet to values if you want
With Destwb.Sheets(1).UsedRange
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
        .Cells.Copy
        .Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        .Cells(1).Select
End With
Application.CutCopyMode = False

'Insert total formulas in Calc sheet

'Save the new workbook and close it
TempFilePath = Sheets("Calculation").Range("L4").Value
TempFileName = Range("L3").Value

With Destwb
    .SaveAs TempFilePath & "\" & TempFileName & FileExtStr, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
    .Close SaveChanges:=True
End With

MsgBox "You can find the new file in " & TempFilePath
```

Comment: Every `Range` object has a member called "Formula". Try using that one. You may need to touch single cells in order for this to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could copy the whole thing first, like you are doing and then overwrite the cells in `Destwb` `D31:E38` with the formulas from the cells in `Sourcewb`. Assuming the range of interest in `Sourcewb` is "`D31:E38`" and that the destination range and source range are the same size, you could do the following:

```
'Copy all cells
'Your code here

'New code
set formulaRngFromSource = Sourcewb.Sheets("Calculation").Range("D31:E38")
set formulaRngToDest = Destwb.Sheets(1).Range("D31:E38")

i = 1
for each range in formulaRngFromSource
     formulaRngToDest(i).Formula = range.Formula
     i = i + 1
next range
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with: `ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlFormulas`

```
ActiveSheet.Unprotect
...
    .Cells.Copy
    .Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    .Cells.PasteSpecial xlFormulas
    .Cells(1).Select
End With
```